# Is there way that delete perspective from 'open perspective' dialog at Runtime

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

[image]

I want to remove perspective from 'Open Perspective' dialog at Runtime.

Please give me advice.

Comment: I think you should work on your accept ratio. Some of the answers seem valid within the context of your previous questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use activities to hide a perspective from the dialog.  You can also use http://wiki.eclipse.org/Product_Customization to remove the offending definition from the plugin.xml before it is loaded (Product customization depends on Equinox Transforms).

See [How remove pop-up menu contributions in eclipse RCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747839/how-remove-pop-up-menu-contributions-in-eclipse-rcp) for references to both methods.