# adding and removing popup menu items for java file

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I wanted to add one item in the popup when I right click all java file which is in the package explorer. I gave the object class as org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile and nameFilter is *.java. But it does not work for me.But If I give some other extensions as namefilter like *.abc, then it works for me. How do I add popupmenu items into java files?Wont eclipse support the popumenu item for adding into java files? And also I need to remove some of the existing popumenu items for the java files.How can I do that?

Please help me in this.

Thanks
Bhanu

Comment: Are you testing your plugin in a new Eclipse session through an "Eclipse application" launcher? (http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#runconfiguration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use commands, not actions. The code below should work.

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
         <command
               commandId="my id"
               label="my command label"
               style="push">
          <visibleWhen>
           <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
            <iterate
                 ifEmpty="false">
             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
               <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.java" />
             </adapt>
            </iterate>
           </with>
         </visibleWhen>
       </command>
      </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

However, if you *must* contribute an action, [here's how to do it](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html).

As for removing items from a menu, this question has been posted and answered several times on SO already, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747839/how-remove-pop-up-menu-contributions-in-eclipse-rcp).